# networkx network_simplex function overflow warning without floating numbers

Tags: python, overflow, warnings, networkx, simplex

I am trying to use the networkx `network_simplex()` function with a directed graph.

In the official documentation it says:

> This algorithm is not guaranteed to work if edge weights or demands
> are floating point numbers (overflows and roundoff errors can cause
> problems). As a workaround you can use integer numbers by multiplying
> the relevant edge attributes by a convenient constant factor (eg 100).

However, I am not using any float numbers on edge weights or demands, **how can I fix this issue?**

Here is the code piece that I am trying to run:

```
flow_cost, flow_dict = nx.network_simplex(directed_graph)
```

And below you can find the directed_graph specifications. **Am I wrong, while saying that my edge weights or demands are not floating numbers?**

[image: directed_graph]

PS: Here is the only question, I found relevant to this topic: [python networkX network simplex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770941/python-networkx-network-simplex)

Comment: Have you tried to test it with a small part of your graph? It looks like you have 100k nodes

Comment: That is the issue though, I first though it is because of the big graph. However, than I gave a bigger graph with 200k nodes. It does not create this overflow warning. @Sparky05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was:

the weights and the demand dictionary contained `numpy.int32` integers. I first changed them to `numpy.int64` integers, still got the same warning. Then finally, I changed them to native python integers, meaning `int()`.

It fixed the issue.